# java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException

Tags: java, exception, io

I have program that reads user input and then writes to file.
After that program reads that file and make some basic arithmetic functions. 
Then results are shown on screen for user.After that I want to clear that file, because it will be like cache for program, no need for permanent store.

It all works great, and I can clear file, but I got such weird   exception:

`java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException`
And program stops.

My code:
The file looks like this

```
2013      Jūnijs              1500.0              80                  125                 293.7               151.25              1055.05             
2013      Jūlijs              1150.0              80                  125                 218.94              112.75              818.31              
2013      Septembris          1550.0              80                  125                 304.38              156.75              1088.87
```

Clearing the file is done with this code :

```
 public static void Clear_file() throws IOException{
                 System.out.println("Notīram failu");
                 clear = new Formatter(new FileWriter(user_name()+".txt", true));
                 FileOutputStream erasor = new FileOutputStream(user_name()+".txt");
                 erasor.write((new String().getBytes("")));
                 erasor.close();             
             }
```

I read the guide and there are written like this :
**If the given charset is not in that list then it is certain that this error will be thrown.**

I am confused, because in the file are just String and double type data.

How can I avoid trowing this exception?

Thanks :)

Comment: out of curiosity, what do you actually expect this line `erasor.write((new String().getBytes("")));` to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new String().getBytes("")`

You provided no name for the charset, that's why the exception is thrown.

Try to set one and you'll see that it runs correctly.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new String("test").getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Output :

> [116, 101, 115, 116]

Comment: Oooh! We should check the time in milliseconds to compare :P

Comment: Is that possible on SO?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I don't think so

Comment: However, you got my +1 :)

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Well, you can try to build a query at http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries But the datetime is stored as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, so I think you won't get any further informations. You got my +1 too =)

Comment: Nice, I found it! A datetime is stored as a long which expresses the number of milliseconds since epoch. But there is some latency on the server. The caches are not ready yet to answer the query that will tell us who answered first on this question. For older questions it works. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/146189/find-out-who-answered-first

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Haha ! That's nice =) You'll have your answer in few days then!!

Answer (score 1):

```
erasor.write((new String().getBytes("")));
```

Here, you ask the empty String object to get a byte array encoded in the encoding called: `""`. (no name). Of course, there  is no character encoding that is named `""`.

To clear the file, use something like:

```
new FileOuputStream(file).close();
```